# Display popup script to make it popup only once per browser session

Tags: javascript, css, popup

Hi, I have this pop-up modal on this link http://my-cravings.com/cravings-group-events-and-services-inquiry and i want the pop-up to show only once per browser session, Is there any possible way to implement this?? Thanks .. Please help.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <a class="modal" href="index.php?option=com_rsform&formId=22&tmpl=component">Please click this to proceed</a>
    </div>
    <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  

 var id = '#dialog';

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect
$('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
//Cancel the link behavior
e.preventDefault();

$('#mask').hide();
$('.window').hide();
});

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
$(this).hide();
$('.window').hide(); 
});
});
```

```css
#mask {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
}
#boxes .window {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 440px;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;

}
#boxes #dialog {
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
#popupfoot {
  font-size: 16pt;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @wehpogi , that give me idea and this is what i did. I managed to put DOM in the code and works like charm . Simple yet another effective solution .

Answer (score 1):

Try to use javascript sessionStorage. Use it in your condition before showing popup

Comment: Hi, wehpogi im still not familiar to sessionStorage .. how will i implement this using js?

Comment: You can learn it from [here hope this may help you](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) :)

Answer (score 0):

Like wehpogi said, you can use `sessionStorage` to store a flag that indicates you have already showed the pop up.  If the user's browser doesn't have `sessionStorage` support, you can fallback to using a cookie.

Comment: Should i add sessionStorage to the script?